# mkview file code meaning

Tags: vimscript, filesystem

I use `:mkview %.vimview` to create a view file under current directory, and in the file created there is a line of code like this:

```vim
if bufexists(fnamemodify("~/PycharmProjects/rl/report/rl_qf_report.tex", ":p")) | buffer ~/PycharmProjects/rl/report/rl_qf_report.tex | else | edit ~/PycharmProjects/rl/report/rl_qf_report.tex | endif
```

what does this do?

(The file I want to save view has the path `~/PycharmProjects/rl/report/rl_qf_report.tex`, but it will be a different path if I clone the repository from GitHub to other directories. I want this view file also can be used in other location.)

Answer (score 0):

That line loads the buffer or file at `fnamemodify("~/PycharmProjects/rl/report/rl_qf_report.tex", ":p")`, which is really `~/PycharmProjects/rl/report/rl_qf_report.tex` with the `~` expanded.

AFAICT from `:help 'viewoptions'`, there is no way to force relative paths. But you might be able to run a script to modify the view file to use relative paths.

Comment: that shouldn't really matter, because the `fnamemodify` will be evaluated when restoring the view (on a possibly different system). Also this is just the check, which checks if the buffer for that file exists, else it will go to it (or load the buffer). But both times, it uses the `~` so it doesn't really matter if the `home` directory of the user changes

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt the problem is that I might copy the file to a different location, so if that happens then when I am sourcing this view file in that copied file, I will be redirected to the original file, which is not I want

Comment: And I found this only happens when I use `:mkview %.view`, if I just use `:mkview`, it wont have that line of code, but it will create the view file in `~/.vim/view/`, I have ask this on another question since I am confused now about the two command, here it is:https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/37959/41836